# Which PHP exception to throw when last method in chain requires other method called first

Tags: php, exception, method-chaining

I am writing a PHP query builder-style library that uses method chaining to add constraints to the query with a final call to `get()` at the end to execute the request, similar to Laravel's query builder, but using a public JSON API via Guzzle for the data.  For example:

```php
// valid
Foo::queryType()->take(5)->skip(50)->get();

// invalid, missing query type
Foo::take->(5)->get();
```

`Foo` is just a facade for accessing the library.  `queryType()` is a required initial method (can be one of many, e.g. `queryTypeA()`, `queryTypeB()`) that sets a protected class variable in `Foo`.  I want to throw an `Exception` if `get()` is called without that variable being set first.  And I want to be precise in what gets thrown.

PHP's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) lists a few options:

- [`BadMethodCallException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php):

  > Exception thrown if a callback refers to an undefined method or if some arguments are missing.

Probably doesn't refer to missing prerequisites, and I get the feeling this is intended more for dynamic calls where the method doesn't exist.

- [`BadFunctionCallException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badfunctioncallexception.php)

  > Exception thrown if a callback refers to an undefined function or if some arguments are missing.

Basically same as before but for general *functions*, and `BadMethodCallException` is actually a child class of this.

- [`InvalidArgumentException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php)

  > Exception thrown if an argument is not of the expected type.

While not technically an *argument*, an unset protected class variable required to continue execution fits the general idea, so this one makes the most sense so far.

- [`UnexpectedValueException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)

  > Exception thrown if a value does not match with a set of values. Typically this happens when a function calls another function and expects the return value to be of a certain type or value not including arithmetic or buffer related errors.

Not really an option; while the name implies that I might want the opposite of this - I *expect* a value to be set and it's not present - the description seems less of a match than others, and there's no user contributed notes to help refine.

- [`RuntimeException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php)

  > Exception thrown if an error which can only be found on runtime occurs.

My fallback.  Maybe I'm overthinking this?  Which PHP exception makes the most sense?

Comment: Create your own type of exception, no? `IncorrectMethodCallOrderException` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the design of my library, I ended up going with `BadMethodCallException`.  Since the outer class was simply a facade, I used the `__call` magic method to pass through any undefined method calls to the internal class variable.

After passing through the call, the internal class variable is set to `null` so as to literally undefine the method call.  However so as to distinguish between undefined methods and out of order chaining, I explicitly check the class variable for null and provide the specific error.

```php
protected $request = null;

/**
 * Pass through non-explicitly defined method calls to the internal request class
 * @param  string $function
 * @param  array $args
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($function, $args)
{
    if ($this->request === null) {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Must specify request type before chaining constraints.');
    }

    if (method_exists($this->request, $function)) {
        $result = $this->request->$function(sizeof($args) ? $args[0] : null);

        $this->request = null;

        return $result;
    }

    throw new \BadMethodCallException('Method \'' . $function . '()\' does not exist.');
}
```